# Rxjs timeout() operator not working in pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, timeout

Hi I've reached a state with the following code where all is working except the timeout:

```
public monitorTask$(id: string): Observable<TaskResponse> {
    return timer(0, 4000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.fetchTaskStatus(taskId)),
        timeout(120000),
        takeWhile(res => this.isInProgress(res), true)
    );
}

private postTask(id: string) {
    this.monitorTask$(id).subscribe(
        state => {
            if (state.status === "SUCCESS") {
                this.onSuccess();
            }
            if (state.status === "FAILURE) {
                this.onFailure();
            }
        },
        (err) => {
            this.showError();
        }
    );
}
```

Also tried this:

```
public monitorTask$(id: string): Observable<TaskResponse> {
    return interval(4000).pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.fetchTaskStatus(id)),
        takeWhile(res => this.isInProgress(res.status), true),
        timeout(120000)
    );
}
```

I'm expecting the timeout to error out and to enter the (err) block in postTask(), but it never reaches the timeout. I've been playing around with different variants, but don't seem to get it right.. This is the cleanest one I have, so if someone sees what I'm missing I would be really thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to consider here.

1. The `timer` emit interval (4s) is less than the `timeout` (120s). So the `timeout` would never be triggered since the `timer` emits every 4s.
2. Piping a `timeout` to RxJS build-in observable `timer` makes little sense logically. I believe you wanted to pipe the `timeout` to the `this.fetchTaskStatus()` function.
3. In that case there is one more issue. The mapping operator used here is `switchMap`, which would cancel the existing inner observable (`this.fetchTaskStatus()`) when the outer observable (`timer`) emits. Most probably you're looking for `flatMap` operator. But beware for each emission of `timer`, the `this.fetchTaskStatus()` would be triggered individually.

```js
public monitorTask$(id: string): Observable<TaskResponse> {
    return timer(0, 4000).pipe(
        flatMap(() => 
            this.fetchTaskStatus(id).pipe(
                timeout(120000)
            )
        ),
        takeWhile(res => this.isInProgress(res.status), true),
    );
}
```

Comment: Just tested it out and using the flatMap and piping the timeout to the fetch solved my issue. Thanks for the good explanation too!

Comment: @Michael D with the risk of sounding a bit pedantic, I think your point 1 is not completely accurate. Let's assume that `fetchTaskStatus` never notifies. In this case `timeout` will eventually fire an error.